# If $x_1 \geq 4$ then **one** out of the following three constraints must hold: $x_2 \leq 3, x_3 \leq 4, x_4=5$

Tags: linear-programming, constraint-programming

How does one linearize the following constaints:

If $x_1 \geq 4$ then **one** out of the following three constraints must hold: $x_2 \leq 3, x_3 \leq 4, x_4=5$.

$$x_1 \leq 4 + Mz_1$$
$$x_2 \leq 3 + M(1-z_2) + M(1-z_1)$$
$$x_3 \leq 4 + M(1-z_3) + M(1-z_1)$$
$$x_4 \leq 5 + M(1-z_4) + M(1-z_1)$$
$$x_4  + M(1-z_4) + M(1-z_1) \geq 5$$
$$z_2 + z_3 + z_4 = 1$$
$$ z_i \text{ binary, }M\text{ large} $$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that (a) you are OK with some ambiguity when $x_1=4$ (in which case $z_1$ can be either 0 or 1) and (b) you want at least one rather than exactly one of the three constraints to hold (nothing in your formulation prevents all three from being satisfied), then this is correct. It would also be correct to change the last constraint to $$z_2+z_3+z_4=z_1.$$ I don't know if that would help solver performance or not.

Answer (score -1):

Trying to be creative, what about:
$x_1 - 4 \le M(12- x_2-x_3-x_4)$ and
$x_2+x_3 \le 7 $

Comment: $x=(3,5,5,5)$ satisfies the OP's requirements (since $3=x_1 < 4$, the other three constraints are not required to hold) but would violate your first constraint unless $M$ were really small, as well as violating your second constraint.